# Token does not return full dynamic path to Media Image URL

Tags: entities, media, tokens, meta-tags

I'm having trouble configuring Metatag for Open Graph and Twitter Card images.

I'm using Drupal 8.9 core Media Image reference field as the source.

`[node:field_hero_image]` (Entity reference field) just returns the bare filename.

`[node:field_hero_image:entity]` (The referenced entity) also returns the bare filename, not the expected path to the image.

`[node:field_hero_image:target_id]` Just returns an integer. (In this case, it is 1.)

I'm reduced to trying to build the path by combining Tokens and plain text, like this:

```
[site:url]sites/default/files/2021-01/[node:field_hero_image]
```

This works, but the problem is that I used the default File Directory path:

```
[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]
```

That means media assets that I upload in February will be at a different path than the ones I uploaded last month, so hard-coding the path to the directory is pointless.

Now, I could change the File Directory path to a string literal like `images`, delete all my Media Images and recreate them.

I'm guessing there is a better approach: either a Token that returns the correct image URL, or a way to bulk reconfigure Media Image assets after moving their File Directory.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you believe:

`node -> media field -> media entity -> image field -> image style -> url`

Makes sense, right? (I mean, it makes sense if you understand core Media and Entity References.)

As a Token, it looks like this:

`[node:field_hero_image:entity:field_media_image:large:url]`

Not exactly intuitive, but it makes sense in hindsight. The Media field is an entity reference to a Media entity containing an Image field that can be rendered in a variety of Image styles, so the token chain goes all the way down that rabbit hole.

This approach generates a valid image URL in the header meta tags.

Of course, AddToAny is still not picking up the metadata when I share a Twitter card ... but that's a different issue!

Just pointing out to nobody in particular that this Token does not show up in the Node section of the "View available tokens" box. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: For the default style, I would use the following token:
`[node:field_hero_image:entity:field_media_image:entity:url]`